# Change Asp Button class after file upload

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to enable a disabled button after the file uploads. However, I can not seem to get it enabled.

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#FileUpload').on('change', function (e) {
            Document.getElementById("btnUploadFile").className = "btn standard-gradient";
        });
    </script>

    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server" class="btn"/>

    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUploadFile" Text="Upload File" OnClick="btnUploadFile_OnClick" class="btn standard-gradient disabled"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this script:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    $('#FileUpload').on('change', function (e) {
        var btn = $("#btnUploadFile");
        if (btn.prop("disabled")) { $("#btnUploadFile").prop('disabled', '') } 
        else { $("#btnUploadFile").prop('disabled', 'disabled') }
    });
</script>
```

Check this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LiranBo/pnpdjx27/)** as a sample.

**HTML**

```
<button id="FileUpload">file</button>
<button id="btnUploadFile">btn</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('#FileUpload').on('click', function (e) {
    var btn = $("#btnUploadFile");
    if ( btn.prop( "disabled" ) ){
        $("#btnUploadFile").prop('disabled', '')
    }
    else {$("#btnUploadFile").prop('disabled', 'disabled')}
});
```

Comment: For some reason, nothing happens when I click on the asp:FileUpload, it does nothing to the button

Comment: @DeVonte Your `btnUploadFile` is a server control. If you have not set default `ClientIDMode` to `Static` then you must reference it using server scriptlet format in JavaScript i.e. `<%= btnUploadFile.ClientID %>`

Comment: @De Vonte, check your dom for the button id, if I remember correctly ASP is changing the id's a bit. if it does you can try haraman's advice...